# d3 tree hierarchy with aggregation and filters

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and trying to build some functionalities. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what i want to achieve

1. Build a tree hierarchy (ex : region hierarchy country-state-city)
2. each node in tree would have a name (city name) and unique attribute ($$ sale of commodity x)
3. attribute value ($$ sale of commodity x) would come from a data source and it would be an aggregate value
4. i should be able to apply filters on the data source ( ex selecting set of data elements by week , month , quarter, year) to see the value changing at each of node level

I was thinking of using d3 and crossfilter as this seems to give lot of flexibility for tree representation. If there is any pointer on similar implementation it would be of great help